# В каком числе согласуется сказуемое с подлежащим?

Tags: грамотная-речь, род

Как правильно: «Более семи тысяч директоров отправилИ письма родителям учеников» или «Более семи тысяч директоров отправилО письма родителям учеников».
Думаю, что «отправили», но не хватает твердости убеждения. Может быть «более» меня смущает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более семи тысяч директоров **отправили** письма родителям учеников.

Выбираем **мн. число для сказуемого.** Такое согласование чаще используется в современной речи, также таким образом подчеркивается активность действия.

Розенталь

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm10.

При обозначении **приблизительного количества** (путем постановки числительного впереди существительного или путем вставки слов около, свыше, больше, меньше и т.п.) сказуемое может стоять **как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа (второй способ согласования все чаще встречается в наше время)**.